# How to set Redis session store

Tags: javascript, redis, store, session-store

I would like to set a sessionStore with Redis (to use with passport.socketio) anybody can point me in the right direction?
I am using express@3.2.6 and connect-redis@1.4.7

I can set the sessionStore as a MemoryStore, and as a MongoStore, but cannot figure out how to do it with Redis

**Using MemoryStore**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var sessionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore();
```

**Using MongoStore**

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mydatabase_uri")
var db = mongoose.connection
var sessionStore = new MongoStore({mongoose_connection: db});
```

**Using RedisStore**   <---- **EDIT: this works after installing redis**---->

```
var express = require('express');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
var sessionStore = new RedisStore();
```

=================================================================================

### Changes for express 3x to 4x migration

**Redis Store**

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var sessionStore = new RedisStore(options);

app.use(session({
    store: sessionStore,
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the RedisStore one needs first to install redis and start the redis-server.
This is how to do it on ubuntu,

To install:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install redis-server

To restart the redis-server

1. sudo service redis-server restart